# iTunes repeats incessantly: "Please enter valid security code."

Tags: itunes

I have a credit card that I use to make online purchases. I used it on my iTunes account as well. Now, however, I have bought a new machine and iTunes complains:

> You are logging in from a new machine. You must verify your payment information.

I am moved to the payment information and prompted to enter my security code. iTunes won't accept it. I have double-checked and everything, but I keep being returned to the payment information page. The page prompts:

> Please enter *valid* Security Code.

The code I enter *is* valid (I know where to find it and have used it before). I see other reports of this on the internet, but no solution.

Is there a known workaround to this?

*Disclaimer: iTunes is not a web app, but the store inside of it is.*

Comment: Is this your first purchase ? Are you currently in Estonia or the US ? Are you using the correct itunes store ?

Comment: Not my first purchase. Working from Estonia with a US address. iTunes believes I'm in the USA.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, if it is not your first purchase and you made a purchase in the iTunes Store before then your payment information should be saved. All that would be required is for you to sign into iTunes.

Comment: @phwd Yeah, sorry, I've clarified. It's the, "new machine, verify your information," flow.

Comment: Well I would contact your bank association to see if there are any problems with the authorization. Maybe also verify that the billing address placed in your account exactly matches that from your bank files. Make sure the info here http://phobos.apple.com/accountSummary and here http://store.apple.com/us in `account` matches.

Comment: @Andres Were you able to solve your problem ?

Comment: @phwd Yes! Thanks for reminding me to end this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because iTunes is not a web application.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is credit card authorization, as expected. Since the address on the card had changed, they raised a security flag on it. I corrected this (twice, for some reason), but there appears to be a delay (or caching of authorization results) between VISA's records updating and the availability of the card on iTunes. The next day, it all worked worked fine.